# Creating nested data frames with variable dimensions

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, purrr

I have a data frame in which one column `keys` describes the format of all remaining columns. In the example below there are 2 such value-columns, but in general there may be many more.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat = tribble(
  ~id, ~keys,    ~vals1,   ~vals2,
  1,    "A/B",   "1/2",   "11/12",
  3,    "C/D/E", "6/7/8", "16"
)
```

I would like to transform these columns into a single column of nested data frames: in each row the values should be split on `"/"` and form the rows of a data frame, with headers taken from the `keys` entry.

Entries in the value columns may be truncated, in which case NA's should be used for the missing values (i.e., the entry `"16"` in the example should be interpreted as `"16/NA/NA"`.)

The following code produces the wanted column for this particular case:

```r
res = dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(keys:last_col()), str_split, pattern = fixed("/")) %>%
  mutate(df = pmap(select(., keys:last_col()),
                   ~ bind_rows(setNames(..2, ..1[1:length(..2)]),
                               setNames(..3, ..1[1:length(..3)]))))
res$df
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   A     B    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     2    
#> 2 11    12   
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   C     D     E    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 6     7     8    
#> 2 16    <NA>  <NA>
```

My question is how to generalise to larger (and unknown) numbers of columns. Also, my use of `setNames` feels rather clumsy, and I was hoping for something a bit more elegant.

I am primarily looking for a tidyverse solution, but other approaches are welcome.

#### Update

I should have emphasised that the output I'm looking for is a *single data frame*, with columns `id` (unchanged) and `df` (a list of nested data frames).

(The original keys/values columns are not important; they may be removed.)

Here is the wanted structure in the above example:

```r
str(res %>% select(id, df))
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ id: num  1 3
#>  $ df:List of 2
#>   ..$ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ A: chr  "1" "11"
#>   .. ..$ B: chr  "2" "12"
#>   ..$ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. ..$ C: chr  "6" "16"
#>   .. ..$ D: chr  "7" NA
#>   .. ..$ E: chr  "8" NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option after reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(matches("vals\\d+")) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = keys, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-name) %>%
  split.default(seq_along(.)) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
           separate(names(.), into = str_split(names(.), fixed("/")) %>% 
                unlist, sep="[/]"))
```

Comment: Many thanks, I see now that I haven't fully grasped the power of the new `pivot_*` functions. But is there a way to keep the `id` column with this approach?

Comment: @Magnus Instead of removing the `select(-id)`, it can be kept and in `pivot_wider(cols = -id, ..`

Comment: Did you mean `pivot_wider(id_cols = -id, ...)`? That still removes the `id` column I think. I was hoping to get the transformed data in a separate "list column" added to the original data frame, in particular with the `id` column untouched.

Comment: Also, I run into problems when I run your code on data frames with duplicated values, like this: `dat2 = bind_rows(dat, dat) %>% mutate(id = row_number())`, where `dat` is the original example. The output is all NA's.

Comment: @Magnus Do you need `dat %>%  pivot_longer(matches("vals\\d+")) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = keys, values_from = value) %>%  select(-name) %>% { map2(list(.[1]), split.default(.[-1], seq_along(.[-1])), bind_cols) } %>% map(~ .x %>% separate(names(.)[-1], into = str_split(names(.)[-1], fixed("/")) %>% unlist, sep="[/]"))`

Answer (score 3):

For each row, you can convert the last 3 columns into a single character element where the column values are separated by newline characters. Then you essentially have a csv but with `/`s instead of commas, so you can then use a read.table or something to read it. I used data.table::fread because of its `fill` option, but there may be a way to do this with read_table or read.table as well.

```
res <- 
  dat %>% 
    mutate(df =  apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x)
                    data.table::fread(paste(x, collapse = '\n'), 
                                      sep = '/', fill = TRUE)))

res$df

# [[1]]
#     A  B
# 1:  1  2
# 2: 11 12
# 
# [[2]]
#     C  D  E
# 1:  6  7  8
# 2: 16 NA NA
```

Here's another option. Same output and same idea mostly, but `apply` is not used so a temporary (potentially large) matrix isn't created. The code is a little less clear though.

```
res <- 
  dat %>% 
    mutate(df =  lapply(do.call(paste, c(dat[-1], sep = '\n')),
                        data.table::fread, sep = '/', fill = TRUE))


res$df
# [[1]]
#     A  B
# 1:  1  2
# 2: 11 12
# 
# [[2]]
#     C  D  E
# 1:  6  7  8
# 2: 16 NA NA
```

You can also use `split` as below

```
split(dat[-1], dat[1]) %>% 
  map(~ fread(paste0(.x, collapse="\n"), sep="/", fill = TRUE))

# $`1`
#     A  B
# 1:  1  2
# 2: 11 12
# 
# $`3`
#     C  D  E
# 1:  6  7  8
# 2: 16 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this definitely works, allthough I'm a bit worried about how it scales. Real-life examples may have many thousand rows. I will run some tests.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improvement of my own original attempt, which at least works for any number of columns.

After defining a small utility function,

```r
set_names_pad = function(x, y) {
  length(x) = length(y)
  setNames(x, y)
}
```

the following `pmap`-based code gives the wanted result:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(keys:last_col()), str_split, pattern = fixed("/"))  %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("val")), ~ map2(., keys, set_names_pad)) %>%
  mutate(df = pmap(select(., matches("val")), bind_rows))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id keys      vals1     vals2     df              
#>   <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>          
#> 1     1 <chr [2]> <chr [2]> <chr [2]> <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     3 <chr [3]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]> <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

This seems to perform reasonably well when the input has very many rows. Here's a comparison against two of @IceCreamToucan's suggestions:

```r
# pmap solution
g = function(x) {
  x %>%
    mutate_at(vars(keys:last_col()), str_split, pattern = fixed("/"))  %>%
    mutate_at(vars(matches("val")), ~ map2(., keys, set_names_pad)) %>%
    mutate(df = pmap(select(., matches("val")), bind_rows))
}

# IceCreamToucan I
f1 = function(x) { 
  x %>% 
  mutate(df =  apply(.[-1], 1, function(x)
    data.table::fread(paste(x, collapse = '\n'), sep = '/', fill = TRUE)))
}

# IceCreamToucan II
f2 = function(x) {
  x %>%
    mutate(df = lapply(do.call(paste, c(.[-1], sep = '\n')),
                       data.table::fread, sep = '/', fill = TRUE))
}


bench::mark(f1(dat), f2(dat), g(dat), check = F)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f1(dat)      1.87ms   1.94ms     483.     1.93MB     9.38
#> 2 f2(dat)      1.59ms   1.66ms     573.    34.79KB    11.0 
#> 3 g(dat)       9.26ms   9.56ms      98.2   15.13KB    12.3

# Increase to 10,000 rows
dat2 = list(dat) %>% rep(5000) %>% bind_rows %>% mutate(id = row_number())

bench::mark(f1(dat2), f2(dat2), g(dat2), check = F)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f1(dat2)      5.58s    5.58s     0.179     164MB     2.87
#> 2 f2(dat2)      4.88s    4.88s     0.205     163MB     3.07
#> 3 g(dat2)    407.51ms 422.89ms     2.36      484KB     5.91

# Increase to 50,000 rows
dat3 = list(dat) %>% rep(25000) %>% bind_rows %>% mutate(id = row_number())

bench::mark(f1(dat3), f2(dat3), g(dat3), check = F)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f1(dat3)     30.56s   30.56s    0.0327   825.7MB     1.64
#> 2 f2(dat3)     26.84s   26.84s    0.0373   816.7MB     1.49
#> 3 g(dat3)       3.63s    3.63s    0.275      2.3MB     2.20
```

I still have a feeling this operation could be done more elegantly using the pivoting functions of `tidyr`, though.